# Llamar facades desde el controlador - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

estoy tratando de construir una api rest en laravel 5.6 , el api tiene que generar un pdf para eso estoy usando la libreria DomPDF , ya probe desde las rutas web y me funciona bien pero cuando intendo hacerlo en un controller  no me funciona dice que no encuentra el facade "PDF". aqui les dejo un trozo de codigo gracias de antemano.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use App\PDF;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('vista');
        return $pdf->download('carta.pdf');
        //return view('vista');
    }}
```

el error que me da es este

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDF' not found"

creo que me esta pidiendo que que incluya la ruta  de donde esta PDF pero si es una facade no deveria funcionar en cualquier lugar sin llamarlo ?
GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si está configurado correctamente, solamente importa la clase usando el alias en la parte de arriba de la clase:

`use PDF;`

Lo que pasa es que cuando estás configurando esta librería y añades el facade en el array de aliases dentro del archivo `config/app.php` lo que realmente hace es evitarte la molestia de escribir todo esto: `use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class`, y bueno, este facade funciona como un proxy, accediendo a la implementación subyaciente de la interfaz.